# multiplexing a TCP connection through a dumb shell connection?

Tags: tcp, tunneling, netcat, socat, multiplexing

I am connecting to a VPN whose gateway is sufficiently misconfigured that basically the only useful thing I can do with it is to `ssh` to a specific Linux host set up for my usage inside the VPN, and then use that host as a terminal. (Neither `scp` nor `ssh` port forwarding nor `ssh` proxying with `-D` work properly.)

I want to use this connection to jury-rig a port forwarding between a different host inside the VPN and my laptop.

I've been able to set this up with `socat`:

```bash
$ socat TCP4-LISTEN:54321,bind=localhost,fork SYSTEM:"ssh user@linuxhost nc otherhost 54321"
```

This creates a listener on my local port 54321 and forwards new connections to the remote host by way of `ssh` and `nc`. It ain't pretty, but **it works**.

The issue is that this requires a new SSH connection negotiation for every new connection to the remote host, which slows things down for several seconds.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to multiplex multiple listeners over a single `ssh` connection. (For what it's worth, I could run `socat` instead of `nc` on the remote side, if needed.)

**UPDATE:** I've discovered [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle/), which is a pretty slick solution to this problem:

```
$ sshuttle -r user@linuxhost OTHERHOST_IP 
...
$ nc OTHERHOST_IP PORT   # works via transparent proxy
```

I'm a bit leery of sshuttle though, because it's almost too clever for its own good: it tries to do its proxying transparently, and allows access to *any* port of the subnets chosen inside the VPN.

What would be perfect is something similar to `sshuttle` that presents something more like an ssh port-forwarding interface:

```
$ sshuttle -r user@linuxhost -L LOCALPORT:OTHERHOST:PORT
...
$ nc localhost LOCALPORT
```

Comment: ssh -D 8080 someone@somewhere creates a socks proxy on local port 8080 .You can use tsocks or something to use non-browsers with it.

Comment: Unfortunately this VPN/firewall is configured in such a way as to block all the built-in port forwarding and proxying of `ssh` itself.